# jQuery event doesn't trigger on pageload but will on click for the same function?

Tags: jquery, function, onchange, onload

So I'm working through a few plugins for a ecommerce system and I'm unable to get my cart page to fire the update cart function on pageload.  The script started with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('change', 'select[name$="[qty]"]', function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(that).closest('form').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Which works for updating the cart when selecting a new quantity option.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('body').on('change', 'select[name$="[qty]"]', function() {
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(that).closest('form').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();
        }, 300);
    });
    $('body').on('load', function() {
    var thatt = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
            $(thatt).closest('form').find('input[name="update_cart"]').click();
        }, 300);
    });
});
```

Is my modified script but it doesn't seem to trigger the affect on pageload and I need it to do so because of how the quantity's load.

Comment: `this` (and `thatt`) will refer to `body` in your `load` handler, since you have no other selector. There's no "closest" `form` containing the body. You need to select the form (or forms) via a means other than `closest` - *e.g.* by class, id, etc.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess that the closest form to the `<select>` and the closest form to the `<body>` (which I imagine is the first, if any) aren't the same.

Comment: in the body load event, `this` is the body, which is unlikely to have a `form` ancestor. Where as in the first sample `this` is a select element, which probably does have a `form` ancestor. I think the issue is that `this` is not what you expect it to be in the second sample. Also... what is the purpose of the timeout?

Comment: I'm not sure it's even needed but I kept it just to make sure.  Wouldn't it still search the body `'input[name="update_cart"]'` after it loads and click?